# How do you do next\previous error when you've got the keymap scheme is set to "Microsoft Visual Studio" on Eclipse Oxygen?

Tags: eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts

Other question have answers about using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> -- however this is not mapped to anything in the Visual Studio mapping.

The up\down toolbar buttons on the console window do work.

But I cannot find anything the key bind options dialog looking anything like "Next Error" or "Next Annotation" to apply the mapping manually.

Comment: The commands that are bound to Ctrl+./, by default are called only "Next" and "Previous".

Comment: @howlger sadly that's not the right command to bind to. That takes me to next piece of red underlined source code(*), not the next error in the console window. 
(*) The C++ parser does not correct understand about template parameters, so my code has a LOT of red squiggles, which are not compiler errors.

Comment: I see. [Here is the source code of the "Next Error" button of the console   view](https://git.eclipse.org/c/cdt/org.eclipse.cdt.git/tree/core/org.eclipse.cdt.ui/src/org/eclipse/cdt/internal/ui/buildconsole/BuildConsolePage.java#n134). It does not look like a shortcut key is or can be set. Please report it as feature request to [Eclipse CDT](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=CDT&component=cdt-core).

Comment: bug submitted - thanks for the feedback